# Merge vertex to face

Tags: modeling

I have a cylinder inside another cylinder and i want to remove the surface of the small cylinder in the large cylinder so i get a large cylinder with a hole in it. How can I merge the vertices of the small cylinder to the faces of the large cylinder so I can remove the faces of the small cylinder?

Allready thanks and cheers!

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your two cylinders and I will do my best to give an answer. Generally, you don't merge a vertex to a face, but there are other solutions, such as extrusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand how you cylinders are aligned towards each other, but it doesn't matter to much. I'm going to use the "bridge two edgeloops" operation.

Here is my starting position:

[image: cylinders in wireframe mode]

I edit both of them and remove the end caps.

[image: cylinders without end caps]

Then I select them both and join them <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>. Now I again go into edit mode and select both edgeloops at the end of the cylinders. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> to select and edge loop. Hold down <kbd>Shift + Alt</kbd> to select the other without deselecting the first.

Then hit <kbd>space</kbd> and type "bri" in the menu. It should look like this. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: edge loops and bridge command]

Now the two edge loops should be bridged with faces:

[image: bridged edges]